# XML Parsing with expandablelist android

Tags: android

Is there anyone of you knows a sample of xml parsing with expandable list?please help.

Like getting the images and text form xml service and display it on an expandable list.

heres the complete code:

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {


static final String URL = "http://test.test.com/vrp/scripts/vrp_data.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "elements"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;

public DrawerLayout drawer;
ImageView navDrawerBtn;

ArrayList<String> listDataChild;
ArrayList<String> listDataHeader;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    navDrawerBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.headerDrawer);
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        expListView.setIndicatorBounds(402,465);    
    } else {        
        expListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(402,465);    
    } 

    drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    prepareListData();



    navDrawerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!drawer.isDrawerOpen(expListView)) {
                drawer.openDrawer(expListView);
                } else {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(expListView);
                }

            }
        });


    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                + " : "
                + listDataChild.get(
                                listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {


    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("VRP Medical Bay");
    //listDataHeader.add("");
    //listDataHeader.add("");

    // Adding child data
    List<HashMap<String, String>> listUnderVRP = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //List<String> listUnderVRP = new ArrayList<String>();
    com.test.utilities.XMLParser parser = new com.test.utilities.XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        listUnderVRP.add(map);

    }

            *****I got error on this part****
            The method put(String, List<HashMap<String,String>>) is undefined for the                 type ArrayList<String>

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), listUnderVRP); 
             *****I got error on this part****
             // Header, Child data
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    //listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
}
```

heres my adapter:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public com.edataservices.utilities.ImageLoader imageLoader; 

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private List<HashMap<String, String>> _listDataChild;
//private LayoutInflater vi;

  //    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
 //         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listChildData) {
 //     this._context = context;
 //     this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
 //     this._listDataChild = listChildData;
 //     //vi =     (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

//   }

```
 public ExpandableListAdapter(Activity a, List<String> listDataHeader,   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listChildData) {
     this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;  
     activity = a;
        data=listChildData;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new com.test.utilities.ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }


@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int position, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(position, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);


    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(myClass(_context), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setTypeface(tf);
    //txtListChild.setText(childText);
     HashMap<String, String> elements = new HashMap<String, String>();
        elements = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        txtListChild.setText(elements.get(HomeActivity.KEY_TITLE));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(elements.get(HomeActivity.KEY_THUMB_URL), image);
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
       return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(myClass(_context),
                "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);

    lblListHeader.setTypeface(tf);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
public AssetManager myClass(Context myContext) {
    AssetManager mngr = myContext.getAssets();
    return mngr;

}

}
```

i got error on put and get functions:
The method get(int) in the type List> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

The method get(int) in the type List> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: Google Knows Everything http://androidexample.com/XML_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=69&aaid=94

Comment: i got several resources on xml parsing my problem is i don't how to integrate it with expandable list

Comment: Just Create a Custom Class with the fields in XML and after parsing place the content in List<CustomClass> and later using the data inside list inflate the ExpandableListView

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Expandable_ListView_Tutorial_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=107&aaid=129

Comment: i already tried that but to no luck.but anyway, thank you for heleping @SoftwareSainath

Comment: can u post some code what u have tried ??

Comment: okay ill post the whole code.please see updates